# Modifying and acessing of variables of a different class by thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

Am very much new to python. So what i might be asking may not be correct. What am looking to do is. Create a thread from mainss and start the thread. When the thread is started i want it to access the variable of the mainss class from where thread is created and Modify the variable values. And i want the execution of mainss to sleep until thread modifies one of its variable value. How can i achieve this? Here is the code i tried below. Comment in the code of mythread.py class is where I need to modify the value of count variable of mainss class

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
from myThread import myThread

class mainss():

    def __init__(self):
        print "s"

    def callThread(self):
        global count
        count = 1
        # Create new threads
        thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1", 1, count)
        thread1.start()
        # time.sleep(10) until count value is changed by thread to 3
        print "Changed Count value%s " % count
        print "Exiting"

m = mainss()
m.callThread()
```

myThread.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import threading
import time

exitFlag = 0

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter, count):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
        self.count = count
    def run(self):
        print_time(self.name, 1, 5, self.count)

def print_time(threadName, delay, counter, count):
    from main import mainss
    while counter:
        if exitFlag:
            threadName.exit()
        time.sleep(delay)
        count = count + 1
        print "count %s" % (count)

        # here i want to modify count of mainss class

        counter -= 1
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using Multiprocessing, a Manager dictionary is used to communicate between or to processes https://pymotw.com/3/multiprocessing/communication.html#managing-shared-state  Note that the Manager dictionary can be changed while the process is running.  Multiprocessing also has a wait feature https://pymotw.com/3/multiprocessing/communication.html#signaling-between-processes

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [`threading.Event`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html#event-objects) and a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/queue.html)

*Something like this,* (Please note that i didn't test this myself and obviously you gonna have to make some changes.)

***main.py***

```
import Queue
import threading

from myThread import myThread

class mainss:

     def __init__(self):
         self.queue = Queue.Queue()
         self.event = threading.Event()

     def callThread(self):
         self.queue.put(1) # Put a value in the queue

         t = myThread(self.queue, self.event)
         t.start()

         self.event.wait() # Wait for the value to update

         count = self.queue.get()

         print "Changed Count value %s" % count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = mainss()
    m.callThread()
```

***myThread.py***

```
import threading

class myThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue, event):
        super(myThread, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        self.event = event

    def run(self):
        while True:
            count = self.queue.get() # Get the value (1)

            count += 1

            print "count %s" % (count)

            self.queue.put(count) # Put updated value

            self.event.set() # Notify main thread

            break
```